# devcon.exe failed in windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I am manually trying to install a test driver from

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/audio/sysvad

I build sysvad solution and got tabletaudiosample on a windows 10 , 64 bit virtual machine.

I copied .inf, .sys . cat and package files to a folder inside target computer.

[image]

1.Hardware ID will be found in respective inf file, open inf with notepad++ ,ctrl+f [HardwareIds]

2.bcdedit /set TESTSIGNING ON

reboot

go to devcon.exe folder

3.cd C:\Tools

4.Install the certificate named as 'package', right click, install.

5.open command prompt as administrator

```
devcon.exe install C:\Users\WDKRemoteUser\Desktop\Debug\tablet\tabletaudiosample.inf *ROOT\sysvad_TabletAudioSample

Device node created. Install is complete when drivers are installed...
Updating drivers for ROOT\sysvad_TabletAudioSample from C:\Users\WDKRemoteUser\Desktop\Debug\tablet\tabletaudiosample.inf.
devcon.exe failed.
```

In the device manager, I can see an unknown device. Here devcon.exe failed with no other useful message.

How can I see what are caused the failure? Is there any log file generated?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late to answer, i have a same as problem,this information for error is put in c:\windows\inf\setupapi.dev.log. I fixed with install the certificate in this [way](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/5ed119ef-1704-4be4-8a4f-ef11de7c8f34/a-certificate-chain-processed-but-terminated-in-a-root-certificate-which-is-not-trusted-by-the?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is opened since april 2016 : https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/issues/57

it seems the SYSVAD driver example, expected to show the official Win10 universal audio driver interface, has not been tested (it is not functional), not been validated, and not been certified yet...